# Upload large files (2GB) to Autodesk Forge Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to upload some models to the Autodesk Forge Data Management API. Unfortunately, the models are 1GB+ in size and the API gives a timeout exception:

> StatusCode: 504, ReasonPhrase: 'GATEWAY_TIMEOUT'

Using the following code (C#):

```
var url = $"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/{bucketKey}/objects/{objectName}";

        using (var httpClient = GetAuthorizedHttpClient("data:write"))
        {
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, url);

            fileStream.Position = 0;

            request.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);                

            var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

            var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                throw new Exception($"Failed to upload object: {response.ReasonPhrase}");

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectUploadResult>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            return result;
        }
```

Do you have any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected, you should use resumable upload for files larger than 100Mb (as per [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/)).

Check [this sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bucket.manager-csharp-sample.tool/blob/master/bucket.manager/Form1.cs#L184) using the [Autodesk.Forge .NET package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge/).

Answer (score 0):

Cause error 416 when uploading large file with the [forge-bucketsmanager-desktop](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bucketsmanager-desktop).
Please check this issue.

- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bucketsmanager-desktop/issues/12