# Uploading a file to storage location(bucket)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I tried uploading the file using postman ,curl command in windows and linux mentioned in the url https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/ but getting gateway timeout error.

I followed the steps in the url https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/. I am able to create bucket. But when I tried uploading file to the created bucket its giving `504 gateway timeout error`.

Can you give me the solution to resolve this?

[Screenshot attached for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipTtv.png)

Please find request below:
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/testbucket/objects/test.3ds' -X 'PUT' -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' -H 'Content-Length: 308331' -T 'test.3ds'

Comment: Provide the body of the request you send. Do this by editing the content of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the size of your model file is too big to upload, please use the resumable upload API instead, see the related thread here [Upload large files (2GB) to Autodesk Forge Data Management API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52892577/7745569)

Comment: May I ask you a favor to test with Postman instead? Here is my configs of postman collection and env for Forge: https://github.com/yiskang/forge.api.postman